# How to remove vowels / niqqud from hebrew string in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, hebrew

I'm working on a Flutter app and I need to remove vowels from Hebrew words using Dart

input:  בַּעֲדַ֥ת

expected output:  בעדת

Here is a working example of how it can be done using javascript:

```js
function removeVolwels(s){
   return s.replace(/[\u0591-\u05C7]/g,'');
}

var word = 'בַּעֲדַ֥ת';
console.log('input: ', word);
console.log('output: ', removeVolwels(word));
```

Here is my failed attempt using Dart:

```dart
String removeVolwels(String s){
   return s.replaceAll(RegExp('/[\u0591-\u05C7]/g'),'');
}

void main() {
  var word = 'בַּעֲדַ֥ת';
  print('input: $word');
  print('output: ${removeVolwels(word)}');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this method:

```
 String removeVolwels(String s) {        
   return s.replaceAll(RegExp(r'[\u0591-\u05C7]'), '');
 }

void main() {
  var word = 'בַּעֲדַ֥ת';
  print('input: $word'); // input: בַּעֲדַ֥ת
  print('output: ${removeVolwels(word)}'); // output: בעדת
}
```